# How to run installation script only once in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have created a react native app.

For this app one simple database installation script should run for only one time. 
It should happen when the app is installed.

Is there any better way to add a condition or any function that will run this installation code only once while installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually, databases have a special feature that called `migrations`. It`s helpful when you trying migrate your database schemas from one version to another. But also, you can use it like pre-fill script for your database on initial step.
2. Also, you can have a special script, that can pre-fill your database on initial step. But in this case, you should properly change implementation depend on each new your database scheme.

For achieve 2, you can have some variable in your database (or key-value storage like `AsyncStorage`) like `pre-filled` that indicate state of your database. When you start application check if this value is **false** and start database pre-filling, otherwise just use your already prepared data.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

I have the script ready and it is working, It is in App.js(entry point), but the problem is when ever i reload the app in simulator it's hitting the database creation script. It should not happen. This is my first app in React Native.

When i worked on PHP generally we will create database once and we will just connect to the database and we execute our DQL(insert, select, update) queries, we will not put any DDL(create, alter) queries in code.

Is there any such possibility in React-Native.

Comment: @Surya I am add some info to answer, check and fill free to ask question

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I am almost doing in similar way(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS).

Answer (score -3):

You should use `useEffect` to execute a piece of your code once.
Import it like this;

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
```

Then u can use it to execute once or when a fuction is called;

```
useEffect(
    async () => {
        const allItems = await fetchSomeData()
        setStatus({ loading: false, dataList: allItems})
    },
    [
        //when leave this array empty this above script will execute once
    ],
)
```

Comment: This will run every time the component is initialized